# Access to script at "file" from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, build, vite

I build my vite app and this error occur in my html file in dist folder, how to solve this issue.
In older react version I just run npm run build and it creates html,css and js files and I use it easily for deploy. But in vite there are a lot of issue when build app. I want to get only this build folder which works well.`your text`

Comment: Error is like this: index.html:1 Access to script at 'file:///C:/assets/index-7e509167.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.